# Getting the median pixel value for a raster/polygon intersection in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, zonal-statistics

I followed the instructions of this [article](https://www.perrygeo.com/zonal-stats-with-postgis-rasters-part-2.html) to obtain zonal statistics for the intersection of a raster and polygon. For context, I'm wanting to obtain zonal statistics for every plot within a field experiment. These are the polygons (.gpkg) overlaid on the raster (.tif) in qGIS:

[image: polygons overlaid on raster]

This is my implementation of the SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE geospatial.ortho06_21_2022_sub_stats AS
SELECT
    CAST (geo.id AS INTEGER) AS geom_id,
    geo.geom AS geometry,
    COUNT(1) AS n_tiles,
    (ST_SummaryStatsAgg(ST_Clip(raster.rast, geo.geom, true), 1, true)).*
FROM
    geospatial.ortho06_21_2022_sub_ndvi AS raster
JOIN geospatial.allbuffers0724_23 AS geo
    ON ST_Intersects(geo.geom, raster.rast)
GROUP BY
    geom_id, geometry;
```

This code seems to produce my desired output, providing summary stats for each of the 1800 polygons, as shown in this table:

| geom_id | geometry | n_tiles | count | sum | mean | stddev | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0103000020647F00000100000... | 8 | 7251 | 5921.466987863183 | 0.8166414270946328 | 0.16005520481227006 | 0.1760474294424057 | 0.9414851069450378 |
| 2 | 0103000020647F00000100000... | 4 | 7245 | 6093.110233664513 | 0.8410090039564545 | 0.10651537882310805 | 0.20441795885562897 | 0.9480032324790955 |
| 3 | 0103000020647F00000100000... | 4 | 7248 | 5920.850203022361 | 0.8168943436841005 | 0.156718020606931 | 0.22542105615139008 | 1 |

However, the ST_SummaryStatsAgg() function does not produce the **median**, and I can't find any PostGIS functions that can deal with this. Other online information seems pretty scarce as well. Does anyone know how to obtain the median in this context?

Answer (score 1):

For each polygon:

- Clip the raster
- Convert the pixels to points
- Extract the raster values from all points
- Then calculate mean value per polygon id with [percentile_cont](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html):

```sql
SELECT polyid, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY rastervalue asc) AS median
FROM
    (SELECT poly.id as polyid, (st_pixelaspoints(ST_CLIP(raster.rast, poly.geom))).val as rastervalue
    FROM test.grid_nh_72_7 as poly
    JOIN test.nh_72_7_tiled AS raster
    ON ST_INTERSECTS(poly.geom, raster.rast)) sub
GROUP BY polyid
```

[image]